# Linux: MySQL: how to use a mysql databases on a mounted NTFS as mysql database in linux?

Tags: mysql, database, linux, ntfs, mount

i wanna use databases in *D:\xampp\mysql\data* in my linux mysql without moving it. so i can work on them from both linux and windows

here is what i did:

```
# mount -t ntfs -o uid=mysql,gid=mysql,dmask=002,fmask=113 /dev/sda5 /media/public/
# cd /var/lib/mysql
# ln /media/public/xampp/mysql/data/my_db -s
# chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/my_db
```

but mysql cannot read the database tables

```
use my_db
show tables
```

gives error: mysql cannot read the directory './my_db'

it seems this is a permission issue. what should i do?

**PS**: there is only one machine with two operating systems, Windows and Linux.
and i want to use the same directory as `datadir` when i am in Windows or Linux.

**PS**: i tried `ntfs-3g`. now mound partition and all it's content ownership is `mysql:mysql`. the /var/lib/mysql/my_db is `mysql:mysql` too. but i still got the following error on `show tables`

ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of './my_db/' (errorno: 13)

Comment: is it OK to use a soft link in /var/lib/mysql as database directry?

Comment: Did you ever end up getting this to work?

Comment: unfortunately i could not. i've provided results of tries by updating the question. and yes... i gave up.

Answer (score 2):

First off, never allow more than one instance of MySQL to use the data files at the same time.  It's a recipe for disaster.

Second, why do you need MySQL's server on both machines?  Why not just use the client on the linux machine to connect via the network to the server on the windows machine?

Third, if you **really** must do this, I'd suggest enabling [master-master replication](http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_master_master_replication) between them.  So each server would have its own storage, and would communicate the changes back and forth automatically.

**Edit**

Ahhh, wait... Are you dual booting?  If so, you need to make sure the entire `/var/lib/mysql` directory is readable by the `mysql` user.  It's not enough for you to just chmod the `my_db` folder.

Oh, and how did you link the mount point to the data directory for MySQL (That's not in your list of commands)...

Comment: thanks for you informational answer. i used it. but this is not my case. there is only one machine with two O.S.s. i want to use a single directory as datadir both when i logged in Windows and Linux.

Comment: I edited that in.  So long as one server is active at a time, you should be ok (Dual-Boot scenario)...

Comment: ye, dual booting. and i use `ln -s` to create a soft link of the database directory in /var/lib/mysql

Comment: Ahhh ok.  Try `chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`.  Also check out your `my.cnf` to make sure it's looking in the right place for the data directory...

Comment: ye, `my.cnf` is on it's default `/var/lib/mysql`.

Comment: Did you sym-link the entire directory?  What about trying to change the default from `/var/lib/mysql` to `/media/public/xampp/mysql/data`?

Answer (score 0):

```
ls /media/public/xampp/mysql/data/my_db
```

OK, have you pointed the `datadir` config in my.cnf to `/media/public/xampp/mysql/data` so MySQL knows where to look for it?

Re: edit:

```
ln /media/public/xampp/mysql/data/my_db -s
```

Oh... do you mean `ln -s /media/public/xampp/mysql/data/my_db /var/lib/mysql/my_db`?

```
mount -t ntfs
```

`ntfs` gives you the kernel NTFS filesystem support, which is read-only. If you want to be able to write to the files, you'll need `ntfs-3g`, assuming it is installed (most modern distros do).

Comment: shoud i `mount -t ntfs-3g ...`?

Comment: i used ntfs-3g. now /media/public is mysql:mysql. but still error

Comment: hmm, does still sound permissionsey. What distro are you running, are SELinux or AppArmor in play?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the new data directory to the list of directories in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld as per this blog post: http://www.lucasward.net/2011/05/moving-mysql-data-directory-beware-of.html

like so:

```
/new-mysql-datadir/ r,
/new-mysql-datadir/** rwk,
```

You can confirm that this is your problem by looking in /var/log/messages and seeing if you have error messages similar to this:

```
Aug  6 14:47:23 tinybeast kernel: [20254.145552] type=1400 audit(1344228443.102:54): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=24202 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug  6 14:47:23 tinybeast kernel: [20254.165438] type=1400 audit(1344228443.122:55): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/media/data/mysqldata/tinybeast.lower-test" pid=24206 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Aug  6 14:47:23 tinybeast kernel: [20254.165718] type=1400 audit(1344228443.122:56): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/media/data/mysqldata/tinybeast.lower-test" pid=24206 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Aug  6 14:47:23 tinybeast kernel: [20254.167606] type=1400 audit(1344228443.126:57): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/media/data/mysqldata/mysql/plugin.frm" pid=24206 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Aug  6 14:47:23 tinybeast kernel: [20254.186759] type=1400 audit(1344228443.146:58): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/media/data/mysqldata/ibdata1" pid=24206 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="rw" denied_mask="rw" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

To acknowledge my sources I learned all this from the aforementioned blog post, I'm just posting the particular parts here in case the link to the post ever goes stale.